# getting config.yml value out of an entity

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get a value from config.yml out of a symfony2 entity.

**config.yml:**

```
my_example_bundle:
    slug_pattern: "/^[a-z0-9\._\-]{2,20}$/"
```

**Entity:**

```
function setUsername($username) {
    $pattern = ""; // need to get it from slug_pattern in config.yml

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $username)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Username has to match " . $pattern);
    }
    ...
}
```

Thank you!

**Update:** Dev4TheWeb posted a nice solution too: http://dev4theweb.blogspot.ch/2012/08/how-to-access-configuration-values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doctrine entities is when they are retrieved from database. They are instanciated by doctrine without passing by the constructor and thus may have not the same dependencies than when you make `new` statements.

Because of that, It may be a bad idea to make your model aware of this.
You may prefer use an external service and prefer anemic models (simple data objects).
You would then delegate all the logic to a dedicated service.

If you don't want to, you can still inject your depedenceis by hand (in the constructor for example). This works only when you sintanciate the entity by hand.

Then you have to take advantage of doctrine `postLoad` event to inject the same dependencies (via setter for example).
This duplication is somewhat bad.

- [Doctrine 2 inject data to loaded models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437763/doctrine-2-inject-data-to-loaded-models)
- [Symfony2/Doctrine2: Issues managing multiple entity manager inside a listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531048/symfony2-doctrine2-issues-managing-multiple-entity-manager-inside-a-listener)
- [Doctrine 2 with Symfony DI Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295588/doctrine-2-with-symfony-di-container)

Comment: There is an other solution which is a nice idea: http://dev4theweb.blogspot.ch/2012/08/how-to-access-configuration-values.html

Comment: it's as good as sfConfig was for symfony1. Singleton pattern breaks good testability.